# Docker does not copy over updated files when building

Tags: docker, nginx

My dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

#config
copy ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
copy ./html/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

How I run it:

```
docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
docker build --no-cache . -t netvis
docker run -it -p 8081:80 netvis
```

Hi!

When I update files in the html/ directory on the local machine and then run the build commands the files are not updated in the docker container.

I have been told that the solution to this problem is to use the --no-cache option when building, which didn't work and to run the two deletion commands before the build command which also didn't work.

I have also tried restarting docker and also running "docker system prune -a" which also didn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Interesting. You shouldn't need to go through those extra steps. As long as the content of `html` changes, the layer represented by the `COPY` will have a different hash and therefore the image should be rebuilt. Can you include an example where you make a change, rebuild then run the image and show the unchanged content? Perhaps use a trivial file, cat it from `html` and then curl it from NGINX.

Comment: To be more precise, please use something other than `latest` too. Perhaps `docker build --tag=netvis:vX --file=./Dockerfile .` and then `docker run --interactive --tty --rm --publish=8081:80 netvis:vX`

Comment: I just noticed that your Dockerfile uses `copy` but this should be `COPY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, per my comments, using `COPY`:

```
# Latest version is v1.21.1
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine

COPY ./html/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

> **NOTE** I just used `html` and left the config unchanged.

```sh
rm -rf ./html
mkdir ./html
echo '<html><body>Hello Freddie</body></html>' > ./html/index.html

docker build \
--tag=68856201:v1 \
--file=./Dockerfile \
.

docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=8081:80 \
68856201:v1
```

Then from another shell:

```sh
curl localhost:8081/index.html
<html><body>Hello Freddie</body></html>
```

Comment: Hi Dazwilkin! I followed these instructions and something odd occurred. When I access the page through the browser it is un-updated, but using curl produces the updated file. Do you have any idea what's occurring? Browser cache?

Comment: After further testing I think it is the browser cache that is the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, try incognito or shift|ctrl refresh

Comment: You're welcome! If it helped, please mark it as the answer, thanks